# Java Equivalent to Spark's Join Operation

Tags: java, dictionary, join, apache-spark, collections

since Apache Spark offers a convenient way to join [pair RDDs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html)

```
JavaPairRDD<K,scala.Tuple2<V,W>> join(JavaPairRDD<K,W> other)
```

I was wondering if something similar would be possible in vanilla Java?

e.g. two maps

```
Map<K, V>, Map<K, V>
```

yielding

```
Map<K, Set<V>>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You would have to create a new map and loop through the keys/values somehow (you could do it with the nice new streams api).

Or take a look a guava's multimap.

Comment: That's kind of a bummer, but at least Streams are elegant.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `leftOuterJoin()` :

```
JavaPairRdd<K,V> left;
JavaPairRdd<K,V> right;

JavaPairRdd<K, Tuple2<V, Optional<V>>> joined = left.leftOuterJoin(right);
```